# Differences between Magento Community and Enterprise when it comes to the newsletter?

Tags: magento, newsletter

I was wondering if there are new features related to the newsletter on the Magento Enterprise Edition compared to the Community Edition.

Is there any difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. The same newsletter module is used both in EE and CE.

Answer (score 1):

there is one difference i found recently that in community version ,it has no newsletter group option while enterprise version has that thing.